# Add products to facebook application programatically

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I'm building Facebook applications, and for my clients I need the apps to have their logos and names, so I can't build a single application.

I know you can't create an application programatically, but you can add webhook subscription to one programatically.

I was wondering if it is possible to add Facebook Login (product) to an app programatically (setting the whitelisted URLs) and if you can send the app to review programatically.

I haven't found anything in the docs, and I find them very hard to navigate into.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What fields/settings of an app you _can_ change via API, is explained in the documentation for the `application` node ...

Comment: Neither of those two things you specifically asked about is possible.